# powershell filter to remove .pdf extension in the name of a file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use powershell to get all child elements in a folder the code I am using is

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\clntfiles
```

this code gives output like

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
-a---         4/29/2015   9:11 AM    6919044 HD 100616 Dec2014.pdf  
-a---          5/1/2015  11:42 AM    7091019 HD 101642 Jan2015.pdf
```

I don't want Mode lastWriteTime Length and name of file without .pdf extension

the output should be like

```
Dec2014
Jan2015
```

I am not sure how to filter that. please advise

Answer (score 3):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse C:\clntfiles | Select BaseName
```

Comment: FYI this got caught in the low quality review queue. Maybe do some explaining on why it works? ;p

Comment: @MichaelFrank: It selects only the BaseName for each child item instead of the full name with extension. Seems so obvious really that I'm honestly not sure what to add. Any ideas? :)

Comment: See, that's the stuff that makes the answer worth it. Explaining what BaseName is, and potentially how to find it. It's a good answer now.

Comment: @MichaelFrank: Thanks! BTW historical note for all readers - BaseName was added in PS v2. For anyone stuck with v1 for whatever reason [here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/06/24/645981.aspx) how to implement the same functionality.